# How to use php sessions in unity c#?

Tags: php, unity-game-engine

Can anyone help,
I have a database having a table containing user information i.E. username emailid and password.
I am making a gaming website for my college project so i made a php to login on webpage and then it redirects to webplayer game made in unitywebplayer. Problem is how to get information in unity that which user loggined to save his score in database. 
After lot of searching i figured it out to use php sessions. But now problem is how to use the data saved by php session in unity.
Plz. Someone help me .

Answer (score 0):

The unity web player runs on the client, not the server, so any php related information you need to access will need to be available on the client, or a client function that calls to the backend to retrieve information.

You should check out the unity manual on communication between the player and the browser. That should get you pointed in the correct direction with exchanging information between the client/player.

[WebGL: Interacting with browser scripting](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/webgl-interactingwithbrowserscripting.html)